# kable() function for long tables prints unnecessary lines when knitting with rmarkdown

Tags: latex, knitr, kable, kableextra, longtable

I ran the following code in a R code chunk.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
long_dt <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)

kable(
  long_dt, 
  format    = "latex", 
  longtable = T, 
  booktabs  = T, 
  caption   = "Longtable"
) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6)) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"),
                repeat_header_continued = "\\textit{(Continued on Next Page...)}")
```

But it prints unnecessary lines as shown below. Is there a way to correct this?

[image]